# Python csv.DictReader embeds non-unicode characters

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I'm trying to import a csv into JSON in python:

```
myjson = list()
with open("stuff.csv","rU") as f:
    vals = csv.DictReader(f)
    for i in vals:
        myjson.append(i)
```

When I use csv's DictReader(), I often end up with seemingly invalid unicode characters in almost every record, things like:

```
\xc9
```

...in text fields.  As far as I know, this is *a valid unicode character for upside-down e*.  However, as it's embedded in the longer strings, it seems this is actually unencoded, and the whole key is type str rather than type unicode.

I assume this is a relic of the data entry I was given, or the csv module, but is there any flag, tag, or alternate way of reading CSVs that deals with this appropriately by converting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at Python string literals. A `\xc9` sequence is an escape code, which Python uses for any codepoint that is not printable or over codepoint 128. For codepoints over 255, a `\uxxxx` escape sequence is used instead.

Python will print representations of values contained in a container, such as a list or dictionary, by default. The representation (`repr()` function result) of a unicode value is printed as a python string literal:

```
>>> print [u'Hello: \xc9']
[u'Hello: \xc9']
>>> print [u'Hello: \xc9'][0]
Hello: É
```

Comment: I really still have a hard time understanding the documentation in this, then.  Does this mean my string is unicode, or is not unicode?  Also, why is it the case that when I try to do anything with this data that expects valid unicode, it fails?  My understanding was that python was unicode native by default, right?

Comment: @Mittenchops: Are those string literals presented with `u''` or without a prefix?

Comment: @Mittenchops: Python is largely unicode aware, but if you mix unicode and byte string values, things get ugly fast (automatic coercion is rarely a good idea). You need to create a new question with your exact problems for me to be able to help with that.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn, but I'm afraid I'm still entirely unsure of what my question is---looking at the document, it appears to not contain anything invalid, and the escape sequence also looks valid, right?  I don't understand what is wrong with my data that so many functions consider this invalid, or how to fix it, or read it better in the first place.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? Python 2 prefixes with `u''`, but the CSV module handles byte strings, not Unicode. In Python 3, you do get Unicode values, which are the default and you won't get `u''` prefixes. If you are using Python 2 and see `\xc9` in your byte strings, then you are *probably* looking at Latin-1 encoded text.